# Why Does My War File (With Camel Code) Fail To Deploy On JBoss 7 When ActiveMQ is Not Started?

Tags: java, jboss7.x, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am new to Camel and ActiveMQ.
I have some Java code that attempts to consume some messages from a different application via ActiveMQ:

```
ConsumerTemplate consumer;
@Consume(uri="activemq:somename")
public void process(Map<String, String> map) {

//do some fancy stuff
}
```

The class containing this code is in a war file; it deploys beautifully on JBoss 7 when my ActiveMQ server is running,and the code is called correctly. When the server is not running, the deploy fails and I get the following error:

```
Did not receive a response to the deployment operation
within the allowed timeout period [300 seconds].
```

There are no other errors in the log.
This consume is the only ActiveMQ reference in the entire application; 
and the deploy fails.

So my question is: why doesn't it start if there is no ActiveMQ server started, and how can I make it start even if the server is not started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a consumer to the ActiveMQ broker with this code

```
@Consume(uri="activemq:somename")
```

When the consumer is started it connects to the broker, and if that fails it may hang for a while. You can tell Camel to start the listener async with

```
@Consume(uri="activemq:somename?asyncStartListener=true")
```

See more details at the Camel JMS docs

- http://camel.apache.org/jms